# shiny app do limma on selected rows

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a `shiny` app. I have a table posted below. I would like to be able to select rows and save them in groups like morphants group1, wildtype development hour:4.3 hpf group2, wildtype development hour:2.5 hpf group 3 etc.. 
Then I would like to invoke `limma` analysis on the groups I saved.

```
GSM814795   subtype: Sb morphant    development hour: 4.3 hpf    
GSM814796   subtype: Sb morphant    development hour: 4.3 hpf
GSM814797   subtype: Sb morphant    development hour: 4.3 hpf
GSM814798   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 4.3 hpf
GSM814799   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 4.3 hpf
GSM814800   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 4.3 hpf
GSM814801   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 2.5 hpf
GSM814802   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 2.5 hpf
GSM814803   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 4 hpf
GSM814804   subtype: wildtype       development hour: 4 hpf
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/BXIx6d-8Z-U/LBDyM0ZVAAAJ You can probably use the **DT** package: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Cross-posting, is this something I should not have done ?

Comment: It is fine, as long as you tell people you did it and point out the link, so people in shiny-discuss don't need to spend the time if the question has been answered here, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DT package Yihui Xie commented on below my question can be used to for answering my question.

After data upload the object assigned to data.frame above needs to be specified within DT package as follows:

```
DT::datatable(inputFile, selection = list(target='row'),rownames = TRUE, options= list(pageLength=3), colnames = c('ID' = 1))
```

This enables row-wise selection of the data which can be bound to an action button to save the selections via;

```
output$dataUpload <- reactive ({
    return(!is.null(input$uploadedData))
})

group1 <- input$uploadedData[,input$uploadedData_rows_selected]
```